# Submitting paid package to Cydia Store

Tags: iphone, cydia

I'd like to submit my app to the Cydia Store. It's going to be a paid package. Since I've never done other than free/opensource development, can somebody please explain how to do integration of my app with Cydia? Specifically, I'm curious if I have to check if the installed app instance is legit (DRM checking) (and if so, how to do it), or how handle the payment and purchase (or, did I misunderstood, but is there any standard options in Cydia to automate the purchase?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are numerous links tutorials available for that.

A nice one is

http://iphonepackers.info/How%20To%20Make%20Paid%20App%20Cydia.htm

---

**Edit:** broken link above ... Google cache version (currently) at

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:aU9Q-zFRHeoJ:iphonepackers.info/autosilent/How%2520To%2520Make%2520Paid%2520App%2520Cydia.htm+iphonepackers+how+to+make+paid+cydia+app&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

---

This might be also helpful

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cydia_%28application%29

Comment: Thanks a lot! The first one really helped!

Comment: The Google cache version doesn't seem to work anymore either, luckily there's archive.org: http://web.archive.org/web/20100324021236/http://iphonepackers.info/How%20To%20Make%20Paid%20App%20Cydia.htm

Comment: That iPhonePackers page seems to be primarily about people selling an extra DRM system for packages (that is no longer available), not about the core Cydia Store system.

Answer (score 3):

For questions about the Cydia Store system, a reliable source of answers is simply "contact your favorite default repository manager" - they've helped lots of developers figure this out, and you'll need to talk to one of them anyway to get your Cydia Store package published.

For people who haven't published packages on default repositories in Cydia before, these are your options:

- [BigBoss](http://thebigboss.org/hosting-repository-cydia/submission) (managed by Optimo)
- [ModMyi](http://modmyi.com/mmi/) (managed by Kyle and Tyler)
- [MacCiti](http://www.macciti.com/) (managed by MacCiti)

(If you aren't sure which to pick, find your favorite package author and ask for a recommendation.)

Comment: "find your favorite package author" that's nice, I'm my favorite author :P Well, we already follow each other with Optimo... And I don't think he wishes to answer newb questions like this one of mine :) Also, I managed to learn how DRM works over time, so basically the question is obsolete, but thank you anyway.

Comment: I'm hoping to help people who find this question via Google. :) I believe all of the repository managers are happy to answer even newbie questions about the Cydia Store.